# Mathematical study of dispersive PDEs

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, schrodinger-operators

My understanding is that there have been a lot of activities in harmonic analysis and PDEs that use sophisticated tools to study dispersive PDEs like the Schrodinger's equation. E.g. [the Strichartz estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strichartz_estimate), or [the Strichartz estimates on tori using decoupling inequalities](https://math.mit.edu/%7Elguth/Math118/DecLect14.pdf).

My question is: what physically interesting statements have been proved from this line of research? Will a physicist/mathematician physicist find any results interesting?

Comment: I think you should ask this question in Physics Stack Exchange…